# Can I use Content Providers to store files and database entries?

Tags: android

I have an application that downloads audio files and stores info about them in the SQLite database as well as downloaded files in the internal storage.

I currently add/delete them separately, but can I use ContentProvider to merge these 2 logics together? For example, if I want to add a database entry, can I just pass InputStream to ContentResolver and add file copying logic as well as insert database logic in the ContentProvider?

Comment: That depends on the info that you want to store in the database. If your content provider handles an insert() you could let it log that. All parameters available that can be logged can be put in a database too.

Comment: Thanks, @blackapps, but let me reformulate my question, can I pass InputStream to the ContentResolver?

Comment: That is no reformulating. That was repeating. No extra info. And still pretty unclear.